# How can I identify which process is producing "invisible" icons in the system status bar

Tags: windows-server-2008, process

I have a server which we are experiencing as really slow. Upon login into the server as domain admin we notice a huge system status bar, filled with invisible icons. If we mouse over the icons, they rapidly disappear. These icons are only present on one of the login sessions (3), as it is not visible on other accounts logging in.

[image]

The picture above shows what it looks like when it has occured. It occurs every 10 minutes or so.

Does anyone have an idea on how to discover what is producing this? I have done the following:

- Reviewed event logs
- Payed attention in Process Explorer while experiencing the error

Any other ideas that may not be so error prone? I would've thought the event logs would give me the answer, but any errors there are not related to this it seems.

Answer (score 2):

When the icons disappear on MouseOver, that means that the underlying process is no longer active, but the SystemTray has not yet been refreshed.

We experience similar behavior also with our own applications and with Dragon NaturallySpeaking - I once had 11 Dragon icons in the SystemTray, 10 of them disappearing on MouseOver.

In your case, the application seems to replace its standard icon with a "blank" icon or fails to load its icon or sets it to early (the "NotifyIcon" must be created rather late in the application startup process). You can catch the process only when it is still active, i.e. when the icon does not disappear on MouseOver.